# Python module installation issue

Tags: python, sublime-anaconda

I am using anaconda3.6 and want to add various modules in it. but every time when I try using "pip" or by downloading file from Github(such as gdal-trump) I am getting an error:

> command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Please add the `pip` command you tried to your question.

Comment: "pip install gdal" I wrote as a command.

Comment: I have also installed "osgeo" where gdal module alreaady exist but in anaconda it is not able to find that module and I am getting "ModuleNotFoundError".

Comment: Not sure about your issue, but updating Anaconda might help.